# ReDim of one-dimensional array throws 'Subscript out of Range'

Tags: arrays, vba, resize

I want to redim an one-dimentional array by "cutting off" the first five entries as they have to be removed for a later logic.

1. I created a record set from a query
2. I filled an array recordSet() As Variant (size is 147).
   Now: size of recordSet = size of daoRst3
3. I try to remove the first five elements of the array recordSet.

Code:

```
Set daoRst3 = gDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TEST")

For i = 0 To daoRst3.Fields.Count - 1
ReDim Preserve recordSet(0 To i)
If daoRst3.Fields(i).Value = Empty Then
    recordSet(i) = 0
Else: recordSet(i) = daoRst3.Fields(i).Value
End If
Next

'First five values in record set are not needed anymore.
ReDim Preserve recordSet(5 To i - 1)
```

The last row

```
ReDim Preserve recordSet(5 To i - 1)
```

throws "Subscript out of range". I already checked with debugging that i is 148 at this moment.

What might be the problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You're misinterpreting Redim anyway. Even if it is made to succeed, `Redim (5 to 10)` wont cut out the first five entries, it will cut from the end and change the indexing base.

Answer (score 0):

Alright this time i got it...

```
Private Sub this()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tmpCardList")

    Dim msg As String
    Dim myArray() As String
    Dim array2() As String
    ReDim array2(0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1)
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Debug.Print ; rs.Fields(i).Name
        array2(UBound(array2, 1) - i) = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve array2(UBound(array2) - 5)
    ReDim myArray(0 To UBound(array2, 1))

    For i = 0 To UBound(array2, 1)
        myArray(UBound(array2, 1) - i) = array2(i)
    Next i

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Turns out you have to write you own custom thing to sort the array. A little bit of an extra hoop. Just realized the final output is reversed but you could easily "undo" that by replicating my initial reversing logic.

Final Edit - this time with less typing - WOOHOO

Comment: Thanks! But now, recordSet is Variant (0 to 142), which is good, but it seems that the five last elements have been removed from the array, not the first ones (beginning counting at recordSet(0), recordSet(1) and so on

Comment: Thats odd. I cant explain why it is doing that b/c my test sub i wrote to figure this out worked correctly. Ill edit my answer to show you what I used

Comment: ill  actually open access and use your code to try and find a solution for you BRB

Comment: thanks for your sample code. Just to ensure we're on the same page: 
My task now is to remove (considering the first two elements) "this" and "that", so as resulting array:
this(0) = "derp"
this(1) = "herp"

Comment: yes, I was just about to inform you  :-). My resulting array would in this case need to hold Card Name, Foil, COndition, Quantity, Price.
IT and Set Name should be removed :-)

Comment: @mffm this time i got it, turns out it wasnt as easy as i thought

Comment: hm, I'll try to do a workaround: revert the array, then use ReDim Preserve recordSet(UBound(recordSet) - 5), then revert the array again.

Comment: @mffm this time I included the unreversing of the final output

Comment: If you are going to have two arrays, why not just store the first array normally, and then copy using `myArray(i) = array2(i + 5)`?

Comment: @YowE3k isnt is 6 of one half dozen of the other at this point? Had fun answering this one though

Comment: I think the populating of the array in reverse order, and then populating the second array in reverse order (in order to unreverse the original) is overly complicating things.  I've posted a CW showing what I mean.  I'll delete it once I think you have seen it.

Comment: @YowE3k I see what youre saying. I guess theyre both equally confusing in one way or another. I do like that the final output in my version is a 0 to x output, but I guess that all really dependent on what the actual output needs to be.